# Redirect user based on search query , Block specific words

Tags: php, regex

**Plot:** I am building a website where lots of videos will be indexed and I want to allow people to search for videos by keywords and sentences.

**Problem:** But as we all know Internet is crowded with bad people and robots who can search for bad words or sentences and I want to take them to a different page, So if the query matches specific blocked words they should be redirected to specific url.

```
<?php include'func.php';
if(!empty($_GET['q'])){
if ($badword ="no")
{$url='/search/'.preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9[:space:]]/","-",$_GET['q']).'';}
else
{$url='/badsearch/'.preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9[:space:]]/","-",$_GET['q']).'';}
}
else{$url='/';}
header('location:'.$url.''); ?>
```

I want a code something like this in which `$badword` contains bad words and I will love if I can have a broad match so searching for assassination will also be redirected to /badsearch/ because ass will be a bad word.

Comment: Surely if you are in control of the videos present on the site, you would want a matching search to provide the most accurate results? If a keyword of "ass" leads to a video you believe is unsuitable, then remove the video, don't sabotage your search system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching and collecting everything took me to an answer. This answer may help other people.
This will also work if user enters DoG or cAt.
This will search for a word after every space so if you have a query like "I have a bad dog" this will work.

```
<?php
$banned_names = array('dog', 'cat', 'mydog');
$words = explode(" ",$_GET['q']);
if(!empty($_GET['q'])){
foreach($words as $word)
{
$word = strtolower($word);
if(in_array($word, $banned_names)) 
{$url='/is/bad/'.preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9[:space:]]/","-",$_GET['q']).'/1';}
else
{{$url='/isnot/bad/'.preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9[:space:]]/","-",$_GET['q']).'/1';}}
}   
}
else{$url='/';}
header('location:'.$url.''); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward solution might like this:

```
$user_input = $_GET['q']);
$badword_list= array("badword1", "badword2", "badword3", "badword4", ...);

if(in_array($user_input, $badword_list)) 
    $url = "something";
else
    $url = "something else";
```

or use `if (preg_match('/\b(badword1|badword2|badword3|badword4)\b/i',$user_input ))`